# Bug while reviewing the queue

Tags: bug, review

I was processing the first post review queue this morning and [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116280/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-platformer-tile-collisions) question poped up. (A link to the first-post [page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/53693).)

So reading the question I felt it should be closed for a reason, and clicked on the `close` button, only to realize that I could not because I had already flagged it a while ago.

There are a couple of issues here:

- This seems to be the first post of a user, but I don't get why it pops *now* in the review queue (6 days later).
- The close vote count did not show up. Maybe this is normal because the vote has been deemed irrelevant and deleted.
- Since I could not vote to close the question, the only option let to me was to `skip` or `No action needed`, and since I already voted, I would have expected `I'm done` would also be available.

Here is a screenshot of what I was seeing:

[image: Screenshot]